# Cumulative distribution function for a Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, proof-verification

This is a past exam question and I just want your opinions on if it's sufficient or not.

I had to prove:

> Let the discrete random variable $X$ have a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Then 
>   $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}rP[x=r] = {\lambda}P[x \leq n-1]$$

So this is what I did:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n}rP[x=r] = \sum_{r=0}^{n}{r}{\frac{e^{(-{\lambda})}{\lambda}^r}{r!}}$$

The term is 0 when $r=0$

$$=\sum_{r=1}^{n}{r}{\frac{e^{(-{\lambda})}{\lambda}^{r}}{r(r-1)!}}$$

$$= \lambda \sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{e^{(-\lambda)}{\lambda}^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}$$

Let $z = r-1$

$$= \lambda \sum_{z=0}^{n-1}\frac{e^{(-\lambda)}{\lambda}^{z}}{z!}$$

Observe that $$\frac{e^{(-\lambda)}{\lambda}^0}{0!} + \frac{e^{(-\lambda)}{\lambda}^1}{1!} + \frac{e^{(-\lambda)}{\lambda}^2}{2!} + ... + \frac{e^{(-\lambda)}{\lambda}^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} + \frac{e^{(-\lambda)}{\lambda}^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = P[x=0] + P[x=1] + P[x=2] + ... + P[x=n-2] + P[x=n-1] = P[x \leq n-1]$$

Thus, $$\lambda \sum_{z=0}^{n-1}\frac{e^{(-\lambda)}{\lambda}^{z}}{z!} = \lambda P[x \leq n-1]$$

Comment: Looks right. Why is it z = 0 to n-1 ? Edit: Oh never mind. I just got it. Maybe you want to make that clear though. Anyway, this looks right *clap* *clap* *clap* *clap*

Comment: Alright thanks :) so are you saying I should say. $z=r-1$. If $r = n$, $r-1 = n-1 => z=n-1 $

Comment: Not just that. All the indices. r = 1, 2, ..., n. Let z = r - 1. Then z = 1-1, 2-1, ..., n-1. Ugh, having given some thought, maybe some, even at the elem prob level, can figure it out, but I found difficulty with adjusting indices of summations when I was in elem prob and hell even now that I'm taking adv prob. Anyway, doesn't hurt to be clear right? :) I think it would even help with your own proofs if you went wrong somewhere and try to retrace your steps.

Comment: Oh okay yeah. That's a clearer way of putting it. My way seemed to make it seem even more complicated. I was just trying to think of how to show it nicely and your way seems good.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean Andre?

Comment: @AndréNicolas ...

Comment: @StephanCasey: I had trouble reading, was working with a poor display. Make sure you use $X$ for random variable, not $x$. I would advise saving summation to the end. Term by term we have (for $r\ge 1$) r\Pr(X=r)=\lambda\Pr(X=r-1)$. This takes one line. The summation takes one more line.